# Clicking on an element with a variable attribute value in a certain format with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, click, casperjs

I have that code snippet to click a button within CasperJS.

```
this.click('input[name="suggestion-to-repeat:5:suggestion:subForm:select-email"]');
```

The Problem is, there is an variable Number in the Name. In this example the "5". The Number can be between 1-10. Is there any chance to work with wildcards or any other possibilities to select the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors  The following may help:

*E[foo^="bar"]an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"*
*E[foo$="bar"]an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar"*

Try:

```
 'input[Name^="suggestion-to-repeat:"][Name$=":suggestion:subForm:select-email"]'
```

Comment: Why the downvote? There is no regex  or wildcars css selector. Selecting start and end will give the expected result.